# Strategies for playing (long) audio files from disk

Tags: buffering, audio-player

I wanted to start a thread on this. A lot of people are wondering how to do it in a specific context or with a specific language, but I was wondering what's the best strategy in general

I see two main practices :

- load small chunks (like 2048 samples) of the file in a buffer. It seems the most straightforward but it involves to use the disk the lot, so I suspect it is not the best.
- load all the file in a big buffer. More gentle with the hardrive, but needs a lot of ram if you use several long files. And if your file is very long, or has a lot of channels, I imagine the index variable could get corrupted. For example if it's a 16bit integer maybe it cannot reach the end of the file (or am I paranoid ?)

and I'm thinking about hybrid things, like :

- using very big buffers without loading the whole file
- store the file in a custom format on hardrive, in a way that it's optimized for accessing it quickly.

So, what do you think, how do you deal with this ?
I don't really care what's the "best", I'm more wondering about the pros and cons of each.

Answer (score 0):

Answering part of my own question (the part about hybrid solutions).

Audacity is using custom BlockFiles format for storing and playback. It encapsulates both the idea of big(-ger than callback) buffers which are around 1Mb and the idea of custom file type (.aup).

"BlockFiles balance two conflicting forces. We can insert and delete audio without excessive copying, and during playback we are guaranteed to get reasonably large chunks of audio with each request to the disk. The smaller the blocks, the more potential disk requests to fetch the same amount of audio data; the larger the blocks, the more copying on insertions and deletions." (from : http://www.aosabook.org/en/audacity.html)

From what I've read, it was primarly designed for speeding up the edition of very long files (for example inserting data at the beginning without having to move everything after).
But for playback of relatively short audio data (< 1 hour) I guess putting everything in RAM is just fine.